Best way to communicate ROS messages over long distances (out of wifi range)
I am looking to communicate ROS messages over long distance (over a 1km) the messages are small (less than 100 bytes) and at a rate of less than 10 Hz.
Any recommendations of the best way to communicate ROS messages over those long distances? Has anyone done something similar and had success?
